# How can I subscribe to cloudwatch metric data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using Elasitsearch to get logs from cloudwatch log group by subscribing a lambda to the log group. So whenever there is a log event pushed to the log group, my lambda will be triggered and it will save the log to Elasticsearch. Then I can search the log via Kibana dashboard.

I'd like to put the metrics data to Elasticsearch as well but I couldn't find a way to subscribe to metrics data.

Comment: You can't subscribe metric data to ES. You would need custom solution for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [AWS Module](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-module-aws.html) in MetricBeat from the Elastic Beat's family. Note that pulling metrics from cloudwatch will result in chargeable API calls. So you should carefully consider the scraping frequency.

Thanks